# initialize json object from a java bean

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following requirements -

I am getting the data from the backend service in the form of compressed file format, which I dont want my UI client to be exposed to. To tackle this, I am planning to have a java bean representation for this data and write adapters from this compressed format to the bean format and vice versa, at the server side.
Additionally, so as to allow javascript at the client side to manipulate this, I am planning to use libraries like Jackson to convert this bean to json.

Now, with this approach, while the client will get the data as a json object created from this bean which is probably what is appropriate, it also has the ability to create new such objects . Now I have the following questions on this -

1. Is this a valid approach or does something need to be changed?
2. is there a way I can enforce this new json object initialization in the javascript, to be of desired structure mappable to this bean, so that any changes to bean structure wouldn't prompt me to change this json object definition explicitly?

Comment: Can someone please help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yours seems to me a good approach, so nothing to say about that.
If you want to be able to create new instances of your JavaBean on the client side while keeping them in sync with their server side structure, then you could provide to the client a "proxy" object, that you can use to create new instances. This proxy, being generated on the fly by the server, will be always able to create correct instances of the client-side objects that are always in sync with your server-side counterpart.

Example (very rough, it's just to give you an idea):

1) include a server-side generated proxy for your javabeans

```
    <script src="/server/url/mapped/to/servlet/ssproxy.js"></script>
```

The proxy, dynamically generated via a Servlet, will contain the javascript code necessary to create new client-side instances of your server-side objects (using Revealing Module Pattern here):

2) Content of your ssproxy.js (generated by the server):

```
var server = {};
server.Proxy = (function(){
    function _extend( obj, additional ) {
       //copy properties from additional into obj
       //... I'll leave that to you...
    }
    function _createObject( config ) {
        var default = {
          attribute1:'',
          attribute2:''
        };
        //you can implement something
        //like jQuery extend() function here
        //to override default values with passed in args
        _extend( default, config );
        return default;
    }
    return {
        createObject: _createObject
    };
}());
```

you can use it then to create objects when you need it:

```
var newobj = server.Proxy.createObject({attribute1:'custom value'});
```